# Bookmarlet: Take number from end of URL and put it in a new URL?

Tags: javascript

I want to create a bookmarklet that will take something like this;

http://www.site1.com/some/random/path/12345

And change it into this, then reload the page;

http://www.site1.com/new/path12345?value=true

Unfortunately I haven't tried much, because I know absolutely nothing about Javascript. I tried to copy a bit of code that does a search and replace on the URL and then tried to add the functions for appending a string, but that didn't work because I had no idea what I was doing or even the proper syntax I was supposed to use. Javascript seems to have about a dozen different ways to alter the current URL and I have no idea when to use each one.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
 var urlArray = [];
 var myURL= http://www.site1.com/some/random/path/12345;
 urlArray = myURL.split('/');
 var newURL = "http://www.site1.com/new/"+urlArray[urlArray.length-2]+""+urlArray[urlArray.length-1] +""+"?value=true";

 var myPageLink = document.createElement('a');
 myPageLink .setAttribute('target', '_blank');
 myPageLink .href = newURL; 
 document.body.appendChild(myPageLink );
 myPageLink .click();
```